# Dash: callback after clicking anywhere on a Scattermapbox map

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly-dash

I am looking for a Dash callback that would access via `go.Scattermapbox()` any coordinate (longitude and latitude) after clicking or just hovering over a Mapbox map.

It is possible to access image coordinates in case of a `dcc.Graph` containing an image, as shown here: https://github.com/AIMPED/plotly_dash/blob/master/plotlyDash_get_clickInfo.py

It is also possible to access map coordinates with `dash-leaflet` via callback to `dl.Map()`. However, I would like to use Mapbox for my project.

Finally, it is possible to get coordinates by hovering in Javascript, as shown on Mapbox website: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/ Is there also a purely Python-based functionality built in without using any Javascript?

Comment: The code in the first link you shared contains in addition to a client side callback using `clickData` a regular server side callback using `clickData` (commented out). Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: In addition to `clickData` there is also a `hoverData` property on `go.Graph` you can use as input I believe.

Comment: Sadly not, neither gives you you *any* coordinate on the map, wherever you click/hover with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

As 5eb's suggestion, you could use `clickData` to return points when click. Something as below:

```
from dash import dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
from datetime import date
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import dash
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.carshare()
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
                        lat="centroid_lat", 
                        lon="centroid_lon", 
                        color="peak_hour", 
                        size="car_hours", 
                        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                        hover_name='centroid_lat',
                        hover_data=['centroid_lat'],
                        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire, 
                        size_max=15, 
                        zoom=10)

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(id='maps', figure=fig)
        ],width={'size':10}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(id='contents')
        ],width={'size':2})
    ])
],fluid=True)

@app.callback(Output('contents','children'),
             Input('maps','clickData'))

def update_contents(clickData):
    if clickData:
        fips = clickData['points'][0]['hovertext']
        dff= df[df['centroid_lat']==fips]
        return html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id='table',
                                    columns=[{"name":i,"id":i} for i in dff.columns],
                                    data=dff.to_dict(orient='records'))
                        ])
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Before clicking:
[image]

After clicking:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, when I click e.g. on Laval (or any other random place on the map), I do not get its coordinates in the same manner I would get them in Google Maps.